# Flashe AS3 Error #2025

Tags: flash, actionscript

Im trying to make a copter game, and I have a title screen added to my game, but whenever I try to removeChild the button is not removing - it gives me this error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
at CopterScratch/gameStart()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at fl.controls::LabelButton/keyUpHandler()
```

Here is my code:

```
public function gameStart(e:MouseEvent):void {
        removeChild(objTitleScreen);
        if (btnStart.enabled){
            removeChild(btnStart);
        }
        removeChild(rbNormal);
        removeChild(rbDifficult);
        tmrMoveMap.start();
        tmrGravity.start();
        addChild(objHelicopter);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show where did you put your addChild() code? Also, to what class(es) do your methods belong.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
if (objTitleScreen.parent)
    objTitleScreen.parent.removeChild(objTitleScreen);
```

Ideally, though, you should know the object's parent, and whether this is actually necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One (or several) of the following; objTitleScreen, btnStart, rbNormal, or rbDifficult... is not a child of the object in which the function 'gameStart' is defined.  The native function 'removeChild' is expecting a child as an argument, and it's complaining because it's not getting one.  Run the code below in the class which is calling your 'gameStart' function to see which children is has (assumes each child has been explicitly named, if that's not the case - omit the '.name' from the code).

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++) {
    trace('child at: ' + i + ' = ' + this.getChildAt(i).name); 
}
```

Read [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html) very informative article on the AS3 display-list and you'll learn how to fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry im new to Flash AS3. Thanks for your response. I have the addChilds added in the main "public class copter" function, should I move them to the gameStart function instead?